# Any PHP Rest framework similar to Recess?

Tags: php, rest, frameworks

I just spend few days with [Recess](http://recessframework.org) and very impressed with the framework. But very much disappointed to see the lack of support, community involvement and even involvement from the developers. And need not mention the documentation!

I was wondering if there are is any other RAD REST framework like Recess out there. I know many 'big - fat' frameworks like Zend, CakePHP etc support REST.. but i am looking for something simple and RAD.

Comment: Did you check out the forums? http://forums.recessframework.org/

Comment: And the IRC channel? http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=recess http://recess.hackyhack.net/

Comment: @KevBurnsJr, I have already posted my questions on forums.recessframework.org

Answer (score 8):

[Slim Framework](http://slimframework.com) is **by far** the most sophisticated and feature-rich RESTful framework I've found, and it's really light and easy to use

Comment: As an aside, I've just written an extension for Slim called "Spore" which allows for rapid development of REST APIs.
https://packagist.org/packages/dannykopping/spore

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Give it a REST**: http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

http://getfrapi.com/ from Echolibre.

Comment: Keep away from this one... it's a fking pain in the a$$ to install and run.